# Integrability over the closure of a domain

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $D$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$  ($N\geq2$) and $E$ a closed subset of $D$ with empty interior. Suppose $f$ is a measurable function defined on $D$ and  integrable on $D\setminus E$, i.e.,
$$\int_{D\setminus E}|f(x)|dx<\infty.$$
Can we say that at least either its positive part $f^{+}$ or its negative part $f^{-}$ are integrable on $D$?

Comment: Only if $E$ had measure zero, and that certainly need not be the case.  Just like the "fat Cantor set" construction, you can certainly find closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^N$ with empty interior and positive measure.